# Why will two column col-8 and col-4 not render side by side in lg view?

Tags: html, col

Hi guys I have a problem with making the col-8 and col-4 render side by side. I can't think of a good reason that it would not work. The col are supposed to work and fill the col 12.

This is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-8">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="pic/Indian.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <p>
          This reciepie is called Tikka Masala, and its a fovrite in south India.
          The orgin of this dish is unkown to me, but I suppose that I can look
          into it and find out. When I go to Indian restaurants I always order
          this meal because its so good. I think that every one should try this
          food at some point in thier life and many will like it.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 bk1">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="pic/Indian.jpg" alt="">
        <p>
          This reciepie is called Tikka Masala, and its a fovrite in south India.
          The orgin of this dish is unkown to me, but I suppose that I can look
          into it and find out. When I go to Indian restaurants I always order
          this meal because its so good. I think that every one should try this
          food at some point in thier life and many will like it.
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Please let me know if you have any idea.

Thanks!!

Comment: Works for me just fine with the code provided. Do you have any additional CSS with `.bk1` or anything with a `width` attached to it?

Answer (score 1):

The gutters between columns in our predefined grid classes can be removed with .no-gutters. This **removes the negative margins from .row and the horizontal padding from all immediate children columns**.

Here’s the source code for creating these styles. Note that column overrides are scoped to only the first children columns and are targeted via attribute selector.

```
.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;

  > .col,
  > [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

can you change any other functionality you can add extra stylesheet.